# pass middleman variable to grunt file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, html-email, middleman

My middleman template has an 'id' variable that I put my html emails job name into.

I know if I change my middleman erb file from index.html.erb to newName.html.erb it will output that as the final files name.

My problem is that most of my grunt tasks require the file name I want them to run on (I've tried using *.html, but it only works for some tasks) and short of editing that in the grunt file prior to starting grunt up they won't execute if I change the erb file name.

Is there a way to pass grunt that 'id' variable to name the file middleman is outputting and also plug that variable into the various tasks so they too accept that as what the filename?

Here is my grunt config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        // Build html
        middleman: {
            options: {
                useBundle: true
            },
            server: {},
            build: {
                options: {
                    command: "build"
                }
            }
        },
        // Format html file
        prettify: {
            options: {
                // Task-specific options go here.
            },
            one: {
                src: 'build/index.html',
                dest: '_output/index.html'
            }
        },
        // Run the text converter
        execute: {
            simple_target_with_args: {
                options: {
                    // execute node with additional arguments
                    args: ['_output/index.html']
                },
                src: ['node_modules/node-text-converter/converter.js']
            }
        },
        'special-html': {
            compile: {
                files: {
                   '_output/index.html': '_output/index.html',
                }
            }
        },
        'phantomjs_screenshot': {
        main: {
            options: {
                delay: 1000
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '_output',
                src: ['**/*.html'],
                dest: '_output/screenshots/',
                ext: '.jpg'
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The description of your setup is i a little vague. What do you Grunt tasks actually do with your built templates? There might be chance to let middleman generate something like `all_ids.erb.json` and load this file via Grunt.

Comment: After middleman builds the file, prettify runs and outputs the result to a new folder. Then there is a custom built task that pulls all the text out of the html file to create the emails plain text version (this is the one that has to have a filename to run instead of running on all files. This is followed by a task to encode the html special characters, and lastly a task to screenshot the email. I'll paste the grunt file above so you can actually see it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your variable in a JSON file and import it both into Middleman and Grunt.